# Anyone have experience with loading a GLB file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, three.js, blender

I am trying to use a .glb file into a react-fiber-three app.

Error says about a GLB file:

Module parse failed:
Unexpected character '' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

My file using this file:

```
export default function Blender() {
    const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, gumballmachinepink);

    return (
        <primitive
            object={gltf.scene}
            position={[0, 0, 0]}
            scale={10}
            rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
        />
    ) }

useGLTF.preload(gumballmachinepink);
```

My Webpack.config file:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'App.tsx'),
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'own-me-gumball-machine.prod.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            "@babel/preset-env",
                            "@babel/preset-react",
                            "@babel/preset-typescript",
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(glb|gltf)$/,
                use:
                [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options:
                        {
                            outputPath: 'assets/models/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|woff(2)?|svg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css"],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        }),
        // new CopyPlugin({
        //     patterns: [
        //         { from: "media/favicons/", to: "media/favicons/" },
        //     ],
        // }),
    ] };
```

Comment: How do you import `gumballmachinepink`? Is it part of `import` statement or some variable declaration?

Comment: import gumballmachine from "./gumballmachine.glb";

It is a file just next over

Comment: I have also tried to put './gumballmachine.glb' into the useLoader

Comment: I don't see a problem with your Webpack configuration. Can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: If you are adding exported `Blender` component into `Canvas` then there will not be an error. `GLTFLoader` is enough to load the model. The error must be detailing something else. Since your shared webpack config model is loading properly with no issue.

Comment: Heya, it is loaded into a canvas. Still unsure what the problem with my file/folder was.I sent it over to another dev which got it to work, saying I needed to add "react" but that didn't help at all. 

Error still reads: 
ERROR in ./components/Blender/Blender.js 5:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file-loader' in '/Users/sylvia/gumball-machine'
resolve 'file-loader' in '/Users/sylvia/gumball-machine'

Comment: /Users/sylvia/gumball-machine/node_modules/file-loader doesn't exist
            .js
              /Users/sylvia/gumball-machine/node_modules/file-loader.js doesn't exist
        /Users/sylvia/gumball-machine/node_modules/file-loader doesn't exist